# Repeat this set of actions forever in node.js

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, promise

I am using node.js. I have this function which uses promises to introduce delay between performing certain actions.

```
function do_consecutive_action() {
    Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => do_X() )
        .then(() => Delay(1000))
        .then(() => do_Y())
        .then(() => Delay(1000))
        .then(() => do_X())
        .then(() => Delay(1000))
        .then(() => do_Y())
    ;
}
```

What I want to do is to have this set of actions repeat itself forever. How can this be done in node.js?

```
//make following actions repeat forever
do_X() 
Delay(1000)
do_Y()
Delay(1000)
```

EDIT: I started a bounty for answers that use a repeating queue to solve the problem.

Comment: Your example shows asynchronous behaviour, and then you used the word synchronous which is not possible.

Comment: Thanks. Changed the question details accordingly.

Comment: Saw the comment and reread the question. What you should probably be using is a repeating queue, rather than promises. Performance on your endless loop with long delays probably isn't a big deal, but promises have a bunch of additional overhead that queues don't need.

Comment: I suspect you're solving the wrong problem here - what is your code actually doing? There are better tools for job scheduling than writing code like this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use recursion

```
function do_consecutive_action() {
    Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => do_X() )
        .then(() => Delay(1000))
        .then(() => do_Y())
        .then(() => Delay(1000))
        .then(() => do_consecutive_action())
        // You will also want to include a catch handler if an error happens
        .catch((err) => { ... });
}
```

Comment: What happens if do_X or do_Y throw?

Answer (score 0):

```
function cb(func) {
   try {
       func();
   }
   catch (e) {
      do_consecutive_action();
   }
}

function do_consecutive_action() {
Promise.resolve()
    .then(() => cb(do_X))
    .then(() => Delay(1000))
    .then(() => cb(do_Y))
    .then(() => Delay(1000))
    .then(() => do_consecutive_action())
    // You will also want to include a catch handler if an error happens
    .catch((err) => { ... });
```

}